# MYSQL - get objects with no parent, and last created objects in parent

Tags: mysql

got a problem on my hands.
Let's say I have a table (name it **pages**) with fields **ID**, **PARENTID**, **NAME**, **CREATED_AT**.
PARENTID can be NULL. PARENTID and ID are related (foreign key), so the structure is parent-child, with a rule that if an entry has a parent, it can't have children.
I need a query that will get all parent entries without children (so the condition is PARENTID IS NULL AND (SELECT COUNT(ID) get_children_here) = 0), and all child entries with the latest CREATED_AT datetime, ordered by CREATED_AT.

**Example:**

Database entries are - obj1, obj2, obj3, obj3.1, obj3.2, obj3.3, obj4, obj4.1, obj4.2, obj5.

Entries obj3.1, obj3.2 and obj3.3 are children of entry obj3 (so their PARENTID = obj3.ID), and entries obj4.1 and obj4.2 are children of entry obj4.

The query needs to fetch obj1, obj2, obj3.3, obj4.2, and obj5 (assuming obj3.3 and obj4.2 have the latest CREATED_AT date in their parent).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it.

this is the table I set up:

[image]

The desired result set is, in correct order:

**obj5, obj3-2, obj2-1, obj1, obj4**

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT c.*
    FROM contracts AS c
    WHERE (
        c.contract_id IS NULL
        AND (
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM contracts AS c2
            WHERE c2.contract_id = c.id
        ) = 0
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT c3.*
        FROM contracts AS c3
        WHERE contract_id IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
    ) contracts2
    GROUP BY contract_id

) AS contracts
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```